# Grafana New Navigation Menu

Tags: navigation, grafana

I'm new to Grafana. I'm using 'Grafana v9.5.3' in my local and I created dashboard which is rendering a local running apache URL.

Now, I want to create a new left side Navigation Menu called 'Topology' similar to 'Home/Dashboard/Alerting/Explore' which should link to my dashboard which I had created. There's a 'starred' option for dashboard but that doesn't suite my need.